# Xamarin Forms Prism Pass a property via CommandParameter

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism, delegatecommand

I don't know how I can pass a single property via CommandParameter to my Command function in the ViewModel.

Now I pass the whole object (CategoryListItem) but I only need the value from the Id property. How can I achieve this?

**Class:**

```
public class CategoryListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<CategoryListItem> Listing
    {
        get => _listing;
        set => SetProperty(ref _listing, value);
    }

OnItemTappedCommand = new DelegateCommand<CategoryListItem>(OnItemTapped);

private async void OnItemTapped(CategoryListItem obj)
    {
        await _navigationService.GoBackAsync(new NavigationParameters
        {
            { "CategoryId", obj.Id }
        });
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView
        ItemsSource="{ Binding Listing }"
        HasUnevenRows="false"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        SeparatorColor="{ DynamicResource AccentColor }">

        <ListView.Behaviors>
            <b:EventToCommandBehavior 
                EventName="ItemTapped"
                Command="{ Binding OnItemTappedCommand }"
                CommandParameter="???"
                EventArgsConverter="{ StaticResource ItemTappedEventArgsConverter }">
            </b:EventToCommandBehavior>
        </ListView.Behaviors>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label 
                        Text="{ Binding Name }"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="16" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

**Converter:**

```
public class ItemTappedEventArgsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is ItemTappedEventArgs itemTappedEventArgs))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("error");
        }

        return itemTappedEventArgs.Item;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Any ideas are welcome! Nothing worked for me.

Comment: could it work now ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't need to use `CommandParameter`,you could return the `CategoryListItem.Id` directly in your `ItemTappedEventArgsConverter`:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (!(value is ItemTappedEventArgs itemTappedEventArgs))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("error");
    }

    return ((CategoryListItem)itemTappedEventArgs.Item).Id;
}
```

then in you **ViewModel** :

```
OnItemTappedCommand = new DelegateCommand<int>(OnItemTapped);

private async void OnItemTapped(int id)
{
  // here you could get the Id property
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but the converter is obfuscation. Just pass the tapped item to the command, and it can get itself the id or whatever needed.

Comment: @Haukinger yes,so i feel your needs a little strange,you could directly get the CategoryListItem data,if you want its Id,only need do like obj.Id,and you also could get the name like obj.Name and so on..

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I know but wouldn't it be better for performance only passing the Id when I don't need the whole object?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I don't care for performance (right now), but for readability. Putting an unnecessary converter in a binding makes understanding the code more difficult.

Comment: @NanouPonette i think in your case it's negligible,but in any case，the idea of you optimize performance is good.

Comment: @NanouPonette so if you want only pass the id，you could do like above codes

Comment: With this solution I need to make an converter per list. Is there no general solution I can use for all my lists with different object types?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can bind to the tapped record from there. You might be able to do something in your ItemTemplate like create a behavior on the view cell and pass the property from there.

If you want to avoid the converter you could use "EventArgsParameterPath" instead:

```
           <b:EventToCommandBehavior 
            EventName="ItemTapped"
            Command="{Binding OnItemTappedCommand}"
            EventArgsParameterPath="Item">
        </b:EventToCommandBehavior>
```

Set it to "Item" and it will still send the entire CategoryListItem.

See documentation here:
https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/EventToCommandBehavior.html

Comment: Sending the entire CategoryListItem works but I would like a general solution for sending only the Id of the object.